# Intel HAXM runs successfully, but android emulator says HAX is not working, why? Windows 8.1 64 bit, CPU-Intel Core i5

Tags: android, android-emulator, haxm

===== some info of my environment =====

```
OS  : Windows 8.1 64 bit
CPU : Intel Core i5
IDE : Android Studio 1.1.0
```

===== the end =====

First, Bios settings have the virtual technology enabled;

Second, I have intel haxm installed;

Third, reboot the machine and check;

```
cmd.exe: sc query intelhaxm

SERVICE_NAME: intelhaxm
    TYPE              : 1 KERNEL_DRIVER
    STATE             : 4 RUNNING
                          <STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN>
    WIN32_EXIT_CODE   : 0 <0x0>
    SERVICE_EXIT_CODE : 0 <0x0>
    CHECKPOINT        : 0x0
    WAIT_HINT         : 0x0
```

Forth, launch the android emulator;

```
AVD info is:
    Nexus 5, 4.95', 1080x1920 xxhdpi
    API 21, x86
    Use Host GPU - enabled
    RAM - 1024 MB
    VM heap - 64 MB
    Internal Storage - 200 MB
    SD card - Studio managed 200 MB
```

Finally, Android Studio log shows:

```
HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
emulator: VT feature is not enabled, HAXM not working.
creating window 43 59 329 583
```

Where am I wrong? Please help and thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figure this out.

My antivirus software conflicts with the emulation. They all use VT.

Close the antivirus software and reboot intel haxm . Then it works.

```
cmd.exe 
    sc stop intelhaxm
    sc start intelhaxm
```

Comment: What antivirus are you using? How did you disable it?